# How do I change ignore-paths on an existing git-svn repo?

Tags: git-svn

I have an already existing git-svn repo with an ignore paths in my .config file that looks like this:

```
ignore-paths = ^(?!(Path1/Proj1|Path1/Proj2|Path2/Proj3))
```

This works well.

Someone added a new project in svn that I now need in my git repo.

If I change ignore-paths to what's below and issue a fetch or a rebase, I never see Path2/Proj4

```
 ignore-paths = ^(?!(Path1/Proj1|Path1/Proj2|Path2/Proj3|Path2/Proj4))
```

In the past, I've always given up and blasted away my git repo and recreated it.  Is there a better way?

Comment: You can edit `.git/config` by hand. I've read that using the normal `git config` commands don't work for a lot of the svn properties.

Comment: editing the .git/config doesn't do it for me (using include-paths)

Answer (score 2):

After editing the ignore-paths you need to

```
git svn reset -r <n> -p # where <n> is the SVN revision where the new path was added.
git svn fetch
git rebase # or reset
```

Reference [`git-svn(1)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn):

> ***reset***
>
> Undoes the effects of *fetch* back to the specified revision.
>   This allows you to re-*fetch* an SVN revision.  Normally the
>   contents of an SVN revision should never change and *reset*
>   should not be necessary.  However, if SVN permissions change,
>   or if you alter your --ignore-paths option, a *fetch* may fail
>   with "not found in commit" (file not previously visible) or
>   "checksum mismatch" (missed a modification).  If the problem
>   file cannot be ignored forever (with --ignore-paths) the only
>   way to repair the repo is to use *reset*.
>
> Only the rev_map and refs/remotes/git-svn are changed (see
>   *$GIT_DIR/svn/*\*/.rev_map.** in the FILES section below for details).
>   Follow *reset* with a *fetch* and then *git reset* or *git rebase* to
>   move local branches onto the new tree.

Comment: A concrete example would be tremendously helpful here. In my attempts, the 'git rebase' w/ no other arguments resulted in a usage error, and the doc you reference has an example that is unclear for non-git-gurus. Also, the 'fetch' only seemed to update the 'trunk' SVN branch in the git clone. The other SVN branches in my clone were left alone, and only a clean, new clone of the SVN repo would resolve it.